# Higher-Moment estimation of EIV models

Tags: r

As part of my research project I need to implement the Dagenais-Dagenais (J of Econometrics, 1997) higher-moment estimation procedure in R.

Specifically, given a T by K matrix "x" and T by 1 vector "y", I must compute the following z (among others) :

z = x * x * x - 3 x (E[(x'x)/T] * I[K])

A "*" refers to Hadamard element-by-element matrix product, x' the transpose of x, and I[K] a K by K matrix with ones on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere.

Finally, both x and y are column-wise mean deviations form but that does not really matter for coding albeit necessary to perform the estimations.

Below is the minimal example for R :

```
# y.vec 30 by 1
# x.mat 30 by 3
set.seed(123)
Y <- rt(n = 30, df = 4)
X <- matrix(data = rt(n = 90, df = 4),
            nrow = 30, ncol = 3,
            dimnames = list(NULL, c("X1", "X2", "X3")))
# Y and X in mean deviations
y.vec <- apply(as.data.frame(Y), 2, function(a){return(a - mean(a))})
x.mat <- apply(as.data.frame(X), 2, function(a){return(a - mean(a))})
# z
part1 <- x.mat * x.mat * x.mat
part2 <- 3 * x.mat %*% (mean((t(x.mat) %*% x.mat) / nrow(x.mat) * diag(ncol(x.mat)))
z <- part1 - part2
```

There are additional z instruments that include variants of the term within the expectation in the formula of z but for simplicity I have not listed the remaining ones here.

My question: I am not sure about part2. Do you think I'm right about the code given the formula?

Any help & suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Have not dabbled into the linked paper yet. Looks ok to me. y is missing, in formula and R calculation. What are you trying to achieve with `apply(X, 2L, \(a) a - mean(a))`? Mean centering? Then `scale(X, scale = FALSE)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's for mean centering by columns, yours is more compact though, I'll do that